# The function clipboard.get_selection() fails to get all the selected string

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, archlinux, autokey

I set a shortcut in order to select a piece of text and open an URL with the selection at the end.

So this is the script for AutoKey under linux:

```
text = clipboard.get_selection()
system.exec_command("kde-open http://www.MY_URL.com/%s" % text)
```

the problem is that the %s only insert the first word.

So if I select "***my text is this***" che URL opened is: *www.MY_URL.com/**my***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to encode the text to use it in a URL:

```
from urllib.parse import quote # in python2 that would be: from urllib import quote

text = quote(clipboard.get_selection())
system.exec_command("kde-open http://www.MY_URL.com/%s" % text)
```

Answer (score 0):

> system.exec_command("kde-open http://www.MY_URL.com/%s" % text)
> the problem is that the %s only insert the first word.
> So if I select "my text is this" che URL opened is: www.MY_URL.com/my

I think the problem is that your script doesn't keep the entire string to search **in** the url.

In other words, the command you are running is

```
system.exec_command("kde-open http://www.MY_URL.com/my text is this")
```

If running on a console

```
kde-open http://www.MY_URL.com/my text is this
```

doesn't do what you want, Autokey won't do it better.

If using Autokey with Python3 you could do

```
system.exec_command(f"kde-open 'http://www.MY_URL.com/{text}'")
```